# Is there a way to avoid implementing a logic in the view template?

Tags: views, theming

Some where I have read that we should use views template xxxxx.tpl.php file to not implement complex logic. I want to show a search results message to the user. The message is not made of mere row count but it has little bit of logic depending on what options he has selected.

I have implemented this logic in my view mymodule-view-grid--apartments--listing-row-filtered.tpltemplate.tpl.

I don't think this is complicated logic that's why I went on and implemented this logic but a question always bothers me is that where should I implement this logic if at all I have to implement it outside and how to pass this variable to this template.

```
<?php

  $view = views_get_current_view();
  $rowCount = $view->total_rows; 

  isset($view->exposed_input['field_location_tid'])?$ltid = $view->exposed_input['field_location_tid']:$ltid = 'All';

  //force to all if landing directly
  $city = taxonomy_term_load($view->exposed_input['field_city_tr_tid'])->name;
  $locationName = $ltid == 'All'?'':' in ' . taxonomy_term_load($view->exposed_input['field_location_tid'])->name;
  //
  $resultText = "Properties in $city: Your search criteria matched $rowCount properties$locationName";



?>

<h3><?php print($resultText);?></h3>
... and rest of the template follows unchanged
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates are for displaying content, not building it, so you're right to want to avoid this.

Drupal allows you to [preprocess any theme function](https://drupal.org/node/223430) to add variables. I guess in your case it would be something like

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_grid(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'some_view') {
    $vars['foo'] = markup_building_function();
  }
}
```

Then back in the template file you can output that var like so:

```
<?php echo $foo; ?>
```

Comment: Clive, I think you mean mytheme_preprocess_views_**view**? From my debug output it looks like the template is processed before the preprocessor. I can see the new variable in the $variables but not in the template. What I am missing?

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, does the update answer work?

Comment: No cleave, Just before your answer I read an article and tried these hooks aswell preprocess_views_grid, preprocess_views_list, preprocess_views_realia_grid
I got realia grid from the export code which is this
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'realia_grid'; These are not even calling the hook

Comment: Hmm, that should work if memory serves but I guess something's changed or I've just got it horribly wrong. You can always use `MYTHEME_preprocess_views_views` and check `$view->name` and `$view->current_display`, that will definitely work

Comment: yes its working but it looks like this hook is called after the template is processed. I have placed a debug code to display the variable in both hook and template. Its printing first empty in template and second the value from the hook